# Monoidal structure preserving order

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, 2-categories

I am working with a category $\mathcal{C}$ in which the hom-sets are orders. Alternatively, we could look at it as a bicategory in which hom-sets for 2-cells are thin.

Is there a notion of monoidal category that has into account this order structure in a lax way? I'd like the tensor product $\otimes : \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ to be a lax functor instead of a strict/pseudo functor. I'd like to find what are the coherences one would need for that kind of structure.

It's not completely clear to me, but I don't think this would be equivalent to ask for $\mathcal{C}$ to be an order enriched monoidal category, would it?

Comment: Maybe this helps a bit: As far as I know there are four different kinds of "monoidal bicategories": The usual monoidal bicategories (i.e. tricategories with one object), braided monoidal bicategories (tetracategories with one obj. and one morphism), sylleptic and symmetric monoidal bicategories. See also Baez-Dolan Stabilization Hypothesis and how this is related to $E_k$-operads. However, I suspect that the "tensor products" here are still pseudo-functors, and not law, sadly...